# Pass {% include param="1" %} on a post to an {% if == "{{ include.param }}" %} statement

Tags: for-loop, jekyll

Using **Jekyll**, I need to combine the power of include / CSV Data to generate table. I tried to use the "param" statement in {{include.param}} to pass a sort of variable to never repeat post templates.

1. Content is based on a _data/CSV file;
2. Titles and tables on each post need to access one parameter (level) in the CSV to get the proper content (the CSV column is showing 1-2-3-4-5....)
3. On an /_include file I have passed :

   ```
   <h1> {{ include.param }}</h1>
   ```
4. I passed the param argument in a post :

   ```
   ({% include xxx.ext param="1" %}
   ```
5. It generates on the post which is fine
   `<h1>1</h1>`
6. I am generating a table from CSV and I need it to understand the _post param="1" inside a nested for/if loop (so i can grab the data from other columns):

   `<tbody>
    {% for voc in site.data.vocs %}
    {% if voc.lecon == "{{ include.param }}" %}
    <tr>
     <td class="lecon">
     {{ voc.lecon }}
     </td>
    <td>
     {{ voc.word }}
    </td>
    </tr>`

   When i generate the website, Jekyll doesn't understand the {{ include.param }} but only when it's inside loop/if (here : **{% if voc.lecon == "{{ include.param }}" %}**.

How can Jekyll understand this param (which is a litteral) passed in a post inside that if statement.

Thank you.

Edit : the files

### CSV file vocs.csv

```
`cumul,hsk,lecon,chinois,pinyin,francais
1,1,1,一,yī,A 
2,1,2,不,bù,pas 
3,1,4,买,mǎi,acheter 
4,1,3,五,wǔ,cinq 
[...]
`
```

### A post - lecon-1.md

```
`
---
layout:
title: "Leçon 1"
categories: 
- chinois-1
---

XXXXX

## Title

{% include vocabulaire.html param="1" %}
 // The file below //
`
```

### The include interpreting the loop to populate the post

```
`<h1> Vocabulaire {{ include.param }}</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Leçon</th>
<th>HSK</th>
<th>Chinois</th>
<th>Pinyin</th>
<th>Français</th>
<th>Audio</th>
<th>Plus</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for voc in site.data.vocs %}
{% if voc.lecon == {{ include.param }} %}
<tr>
  <td class="lecon">
     <a href="{{ lecon }}" target="_blank"> {{ voc.lecon }}</a>
  </td>
  <td class="hsk">
    <a href="{{ hsk }}">  {{ voc.hsk }}</a>
  </td>
  <td lang="zh-Hans">
   {{ voc.chinois}}
  </td>  
  <td class="pinyin">
      {{ voc.pinyin }}
  </td> 
  <td class="alpha" lang="fr">
      {{ voc.francais }}
  </td>  
</tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

### Current result

The source code show a huge blank just after

[image]

So i want the post displaying tabular data but only **if csv lecon = 1**. I will save this template so i can show the same pattern when lecon = 2, lecon = 3 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing double quotes and curly braces might do the job `{% if voc.lecon == include.param %}`.

Comment: It doesnt work since I will need to use {{ include.param }} which would be 1, 2, 3, 4 depending on the post.

I tried to remove the quote and it doesn't work. If i put {% if 1 == "1" %}equal{% else %}not equal{% endif %}, the page generated will just work for the integer '1' (i need it to be equal to the voc.lecon (between 1 and 19).

Comment: Sorry ` {% if 1 == "1" %}equal{% else %}not equal{% endif %}` was an example to show inequality of integer and strings. Can you push your code to a github repository ? It will be easier to help.

Comment: I added the main part of the 3 files necessary : CSV + Post + Include.

Comment: Amazing, Jekyll doc lacks a lot of stuff. Can you explain why these curly braces were blocking the generation ?